# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm just learning to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation but can't get it to work, i have searched all over the web and can't find a solution

I am making a clock,
When i test it the arrow doesn't rotate straight, but it moves at the same time.

```
-(void)tick{

NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger units = NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:units fromDate:[NSDate date]];

CGFloat secsAngle = components.second*M_PI*2.0/60;

self.secondHand.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(secsAngle);

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're doing this to learn, or because you want to create a clock?

Comment: It is just to learn about rotation

Comment: So the answer is your centre of rotation of `secondHand` as per @matt

Comment: So how can i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when testing, use a known good value, like `M_PI/2.0`, instead of your `secsAngle` which could be anything.

Second, keep in mind that rotation is around the center of the view/layer by default. You can change that, but it's up to you to change it.